# $\{<M>: M \text{ is a finite automata and L(M) contains a word of form } a^ib^j\}$ is decidable?

Tags: finite-automata, undecidability

How can we show that the language $K = \{<M>: M \text{ is a finite automata and L(M) contains a word of form } a^ib^j\}$ is decidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\hat M$ be the DFA for the language $L(a^*b^*)$ (aka, words of the form $a^ib^j$).

Construct the intersection DFA between $M$ and $\hat M$, and call it $M'$. Now, check if $L(M')=\emptyset$. If it does, reject. Otherwise, accept.

Here is useful material about [intersection DFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780521/how-to-use-the-intersection-construction-to-form-a-dfa/7798776) and about [checking the empty-ness of the DFA language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18616/decide-whether-a-dfa-accepts-the-empty-language)