# Is language decideable (subset)?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm working on a proof for following question

> $L=\{(R,S)\mid \text{R,S are regular expressions and } L(R)\subset L(S)\}$. Show that this language is/isn't decidable.

A language is decidable iff we have a Turing machine that halts for all input strings. If $L$ is regular, we can construct a DFA and therefore a Turing machine. Now we just have to show that this DFA/TM accepts/declines every input.

At least that's what I was told. But isn't it sufficient to show that $L$ is regular? Since reg. languages have a DFA and im pretty sure a DFA is decidable (because it can be converted to a TM and is finite)?

Since $L(R)\subset L(S) \Rightarrow L(R)\cap L(S) = L(R)$ we get that $L=L(R) \Rightarrow L$ regular?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Decidability_properties, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18616/755

Comment: @D.W. Okay, so the first 2 links confirm, that $L$ is in fact decidable. I don't really get the meaning from the 3rd link.

Comment: If you can answer your question now, may I invite you to write an answer below?

Comment: @D.W. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet. Hopefully, I'll find one in the next couple days.