# Is there a algorithm to determine if a regular language (expression) is subset of another?

Tags: computability, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Given two regular languages (fx given by it's accepting regular expression), is there an algorithm to determine if one is a subset of the other?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I suggest that you split this into two posts, and ask each question in a separate post.  I've edited this post to focus on the first question.  You can post your second question in a separate post (using the 'Ask Question' button).  I expect that the former is likely answered in standard textbooks on automata theory.  What resources have you consulted?  What have you found so far?

Comment: It is interesting that we can test inclusion when we can test equivalence, because regular languages/expressions are closed under union: $L\subseteq R$ iff $L\cup R = R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an algorithm for it, but there is unlikely to be an efficient algorithm.

Notice that you can convert between a regular expression and a NFA in polynomial time.  Moreover, determining whether one regular language is a subset of another, if both are represented as NFAs, is PSPACE-complete.  Therefore, there is unlikely to be a polynomial-time algorithm for this, unless there is a huge surprise in complexity theory.

See [Is there an efficient test for if an NFA accepts a subset of another NFA?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9954/755).  Related: [Is language decideable (subset)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139430/755).